# Is it possible to use ngOptions to get an array of objects inside an array of objects

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-options

I have this `JSON` structure:

```
$scope.menus = [
   {  
      "name":"about",
      "url":"/about",
      "submenus":[  
         {  
            "name":"company",
            "url":"/aboutcompany"
         },
         {  
            "name":"jobs",
            "url":"/jobs"
         }
      ]
   }
];
```

Is it possible to access to the *submenu* using `ngOptions`?

Comment: I have a drop down menu that once you select an option it should show the submenu in a select tag

Comment: Do you mean show submenu on mouseover or on select?

Comment: No I mean that I have two section. First it is a drop down menu and the second one is a <select></select>. So I want that when I select an option from the dropdown menu show its submenu on the <select></select>

Comment: They are not related much I'd say. You'll need to get the menu you selected from the dropdown and assign it to a `scope` variable, and then `ng-options` on that variable.

Comment: Ok cool I was already trying that and It work

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can, first you should iterate inside the *menu* objects, then you can make the select for each *submenu* array, as follows:

```js
(function() {
  "use strict";
  angular.module('app', [])
    .controller('mainCtrl', function($scope) {
      $scope.selectedSubmenus = [];
      $scope.menus = [{
        "name": "home",
        "url": "/home",
        "submenus": [{
          "name": "employee",
          "url": "/aboutemployee"
        }, {
          "name": "something",
          "url": "/something"
        }]
      }, {
        "name": "about",
        "url": "/about",
        "submenus": [{
          "name": "company",
          "url": "/aboutcompany"
        }, {
          "name": "jobs",
          "url": "/jobs"
        }]
      }];
    });
})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="mainCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="menu in menus track by $index">
    <strong>Menu name: </strong><span ng-bind="menu.name"></span>
    <select ng-options="submenu as submenu.name for submenu in menu.submenus" ng-model="selectedSubmenus[$index]">
      <option value="">Select something</option>
    </select>
    <hr>
  </div>
  Selecteds: <pre ng-bind="selectedSubmenus | json"></pre>
</body>

</html>
```